# pass struct of arrays into function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, moving-average

I am trying to pass a struct of 2D arrays and to do calculations on them.

```
typedef struct{
    float X[80][2];
    float Y[80][2];
    float Z[80][2];
    int T[80][2];
    int K[80];
} STATS;

void MovingAverage(STATS *stat_array, int last_stat) {
    //Average = Average(Prev) + (ValueToAverage/n) - (Average(Prev)/n)
    stat_array->**X**[last_stat][0] =  stat_array->**X**[last_stat][0] +
        (stat_array->**X**[last_stat][1] / stat_array->T[last_stat][0]) -
        (stat_array->**X**[last_stat][0] / stat_array->T[last_stat][0]);
}
```

calling the function:

```
MovingAverage(*stat_array, last_stat);
```

**My question is:**

how do I access in a generic way to X Y and Z inside MovingAverage function?

---

**Edit:**

```
void MovingAverage(STATS *stat_array, int last_stat, (char *(array_idx)) { 
//Average = Average(Prev) + (ValueToAverage/n) - (Average(Prev)/n)
    stat_array->**array_idx**[last_stat][0] = 
                stat_array->**array_idx**[last_stat][0] + 
                (stat_array->**array_idx**[last_stat][1] / 
                stat_array->T[last_stat][0]) - 
                (stat_array->**array_idx**[last_stat][0] / 
                stat_array->T[last_stat][0]); 
}
```

I know it won't work, but just to demonstrate my willings,

Comment: not sure what you're asking..? `stat_array->X` will access `X`, `stat_array->Y` will access `Y`, etc. If you're trying to **bold** `X`, `Y`, and `Z` above, that's not going to work in a code block. If that's your actual syntax, get rid of it, that won't compile. How do you declare `stat_array` before you call `MovingAverage`?

Comment: I am declaring stat_array as: STATS stat_array;

I would like to access the arrays like this:

stat_array->X/Y/Z , but when in generic way, not like:
stat_array->X
stat_array->Y

Comment: You want to access `X`, `Y`, and `Z` simultaneously with one expression?

Comment: I am declaring stat_array as: STATS stat_array;
maybe this will be more clear:
MovingAverage(&stat_array, last_stat,(char *)"X");

Comment: correct @yano, I would like to access them in one statement

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there. But I think I know what you're getting at... You want to pass in a character `'X'`, `'Y'`, etc and then just do `stat_array->myChar` throughout? No you can't do that, perhaps except with some preprocessor "magic" that would be terrible practice. To do that, write a function that accepts a `float myArray[80][2]` as an argument and pass `X`, `Y`, and `Z` to that function.

Comment: The proper way to call the function is: `STATS stat_array; MovingAverage(&stat_array, last_stat);` OR The proper way to call the function is: `STATS *stat_array = /* malloc a new one */; MovingAverage(stat_array, last_stat);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody here (not me) could probably come up with some preprocessor magic to do what you're asking, but that is a solution I would not pursue.  I consider it bad practice since macros can quickly get hairy and tough to debug.  You can't have "variables" inside your source code, if that makes sense.  During the build procedure, one of the first things that runs is the preprocessor, which resolves all your macros.  It then passes that source code to the compiler.  The compiler is not going to do any text substitutions for you, it cranks on the source code it has.  To achieve what you want, write a function that operates on the type you want, and call that function with all your types.  I'd change your `MovingAverage` function to something like this:

```
void MovingAverage(float arr[80][2], const int T[80][2], int last_stat)
{
  arr[last_stat][0] = ... // whatever calculation you want to do here
}

int main(void)
{
  STATS stat_array;
  int last_stat;
  // .. initialize stat_array and last_stat

  // now call MovingAverage with each of your 3 arrays
  MovingAverage(stat_array.X, stat_array.T, last_stat);
  MovingAverage(stat_array.Y, stat_array.T, last_stat);
  MovingAverage(stat_array.Z, stat_array.T, last_stat);

  ...
  return 0;
}
```